# Salvar informações lista em txt MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Boa tarde pessoal, como sou novo em mvc gostaria de uma ajuda se possível de vocês, estou tentando pegar alguns dados de minha lista  adicionar os mesmo em um arquivo txt e salvar em minha máquina, oque esta acorrendo é que o arquivo é gerado em meu c:\ porém, não estou conseguindo escrever as informações que vem da minha lista dentro do arquivo, poderiam se possível me dar uma ajuda. Segue exemplo do meu controller.

```html
        public IActionResult Exportar(DateTime dateTime, DateTime dateTimeFinal)
        {


            var Layout = _context.RegistroDePontos.Where(e => e.data >= dateTime && e.data <= dateTimeFinal).ToList();
                                                  
            string nomeArquivo = @"C:\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".txt";
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(nomeArquivo, true);
            
            for(int i = 0; i < Layout.Count; i++)

                 writer.WriteLine(Layout[i].ToString());
            
            writer.Close();
           
            return View("Exportar",Layout);
        }
```

Comment: você quer gravar o arquivo no servidor ou devolver ele preenchido para o usuário que está utilizando a sua aplicação?

Comment: Não tem "nada" de errado no seu programa... ou você não tem permissão de escrita ou seu `context.RegistroDePontos` não está retornando nada nas condições do `Where()`...

Comment: No registro de ponto a propriedade retorna somente a Data ou uma Data e Hora?

Comment: Leandro, Obrigado pelo seu fedback, consegui resolver problema. Vlewww

Comment: Se a solução não foi pela minha resposta, o ideal é você postar uma resposta com a sua resolução. Mas se foi, seria bacana você marcar como aceita para que pergunta seja concluída e isso possa ser útil para outros usuários.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando escrever um objeto como string, sem informar o que exatamente você quer apresentar no arquivo. Veja abaixo o exemplo com uma construção fictícia.

```
public class RegistroDePonto
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

Exemplo de leitura da coleção e escrita no arquivo

```
//simulando a sua consulta
var layout = new List<RegistroDePontos>
{
    new RegistroDePontos { Nome = "Fulano", Data = DateTime.Parse("2020-03-27 08:30:00"), Tipo = "ENTRADA"},
    new RegistroDePontos { Nome = "Fulano", Data = DateTime.Parse("2020-03-27 12:00:00"), Tipo = "INTERVALO"},
    new RegistroDePontos { Nome = "Fulano", Data = DateTime.Parse("2020-03-27 13:00:00"), Tipo = "RETORNO"},
    new RegistroDePontos { Nome = "Fulano", Data = DateTime.Parse("2020-03-27 17:30:00"), Tipo = "SAÍDA"}
};

string nomeArquivo = @"C:\Temp\teste_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".txt";

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(nomeArquivo, true))
{
    foreach (var registro in layout)
        writer.WriteLine($"{registro.Data} - {registro.Nome} - {registro.Tipo}");
}
```

**Output:**

```
27/03/2020 08:30:00 - Fulano - ENTRADA 
27/03/2020 12:00:00 - Fulano - INTERVALO 
27/03/2020 13:00:00 - Fulano - RETORNO 
27/03/2020 17:30:00 - Fulano - SAÍDA
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo pela sua ajuda. Abraço...